# UINavigationBar.appearance() wont accept UIColor defined by RGB or HUE

Tags: swift, uinavigationbar

I am trying to change the navigation bar colour. I've tried many approaches presented here on stackoverflow, but none of them accept UIColor as RGB or HUE.

The following code on AppDelegate can change the colour to a certain extent.

But for some reason it only accept the pre-defined colours

```
UIColor.blackColor()
UIColor.whiteColor()
UIColor.greeColor()
```

While I need a more specific colour defined by RGB like:

```
UIColor(red: 206, green: 50, blue: 34, alpha: 1)
```

Here is the code I am using

```
  @UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?


    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {


        // CHANGE NAV BAR COLOUR **********************************************

        var navigationBarAppearace = UINavigationBar.appearance()

        //changes content color
        navigationBarAppearace.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

        //changes bar color

        //WORKS FINE
        navigationBarAppearace.barTintColor =  UIColor.blackColor()

        //DO NOT WORK
//        navigationBarAppearace.barTintColor =  UIColor(hue: 203, saturation: 31, brightness: 44, alpha: 1)
//        navigationBarAppearace.barTintColor = UIColor(red: 206, green: 50, blue: 34, alpha: 1)


        // Override point for customization after application launch.

        return true
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just you have to divide it with 255

```
navigationBarAppearace.barTintColor = UIColor(red: 206/255.0, green: 50/255.0, blue: 34/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
```

Comment: Thanks for that, it worked! Sorry for asking such a basic question.